# Copilot suggests only line by line

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Copilot suggests only line by line instead of a whole block. I've seen issues a year ago which were actually a copilot bug but I can't find any hints for the current version. Is there a setting to enable it or do I have to switch anything off in VS Code?

Comment: "_I've seen issues a year ago_" links please? And can you add a procedure to reproduce what you observe and tell us clearly what you expect to observe?